# How to Hide Scans by name in a Point Cloud for a View (Revit API, C#)

Tags: c#, revit-api

How to Hide Scans by name in a Point Cloud for a View
I have a point cloud that is displayed in the current view. For this view, I want to hide a scan named "scan_001". I've seen options like using PointCloudOverrideSettings and PointCloudOverrides in the Revit API, as shown in the following code snippet:

```
Document doc = commandData.Application.ActiveUIDocument.Document;
View activeView = commandData.Application.ActiveUIDocument.ActiveView;

string targetScanName = "scan_001";
bool shouldEnable = false; // Set to false to hide the scan

using (Transaction trans = new Transaction(doc, "Toggle Specific Point Cloud Scan"))
{
    trans.Start();

    // Find all point cloud instances in the active view
    IEnumerable<PointCloudInstance> pointClouds = new FilteredElementCollector(doc, activeView.Id)
        .OfClass(typeof(PointCloudInstance))
        .Cast<PointCloudInstance>();

    foreach (PointCloudInstance pci in pointClouds)
    {
        // Check if the point cloud contains the target scan
        if (pci.GetScans().Contains(targetScanName))
        {
            PointCloudOverrideSettings overrideSettings = new PointCloudOverrideSettings
            {
                Visible = shouldEnable
            };

            PointCloudOverrides pco = new PointCloudOverrides();
            pco.SetPointCloudScanOverrideSettings(pci.Id, overrideSettings, targetScanName, doc);
        }
    }

    doc.Regenerate();
    trans.Commit();
}
```

However, as I understand it, this is a general setting for the point cloud, not a visibility setting for the specific view. I need to access the "checkboxes" in the Visibility/Graphics Override for the current view and override them for this specific view only. Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can hide individual `Element` objects on a per-view basis. However, looking at your code, it seems to me that the entire point cloud is an `Element`, and the individual scans are sub-objects of some kind.

Comment: Searching the Internet for [revit point cloud hide scan per view](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=revit+point+cloud+hide+scan+per+view) brought up an article on how to [manage the point cloud visibility in Revit 3D view with the SONA API](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/manage-point-cloud-visibility-revit-3d-view-sonas-api-pierre-navarra/) that seems to hint at the possibility of setting visibility for individual scans. And if it is possible at all, then you can do it too.